# How to use Entrypoint.sh in ELK Stack with Docker compose?

Tags: bash, docker, elasticsearch

My issue is related to Docker compose to wait Kibana till Elasticsearch stayed up. After that Kibana will start, below codes written for this issue. But it is created an error:

```
**Step 6/6 : RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
---> Running in 2e2d9c229ced
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
ERROR: Service 'kibana' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x entrypoint.sh' returned a non-zero code**
```

Dockerfile in Kibana:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.2

COPY ./config/kibana.yml /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml

COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

USER root

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
```

**entrypoint.sh: in kibana**

```
# Wait for the Elasticsearch container to be ready before starting Kibana.

    echo "Stalling for Elasticsearch"
    while true; do
    nc -q 1 elasticsearch 9200 2>/dev/null && break 
    done

    echo "Starting Kibana"
   /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker
```

Comment: Where's the shebang? Are you missing it? Are you running on not 64 bit architecture? Can you post docker version and your `uname -a`?

Comment: the RUN must come before the ENTRYPOINT...

Comment: No @samthegolden, you can configure entrypoint before run.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not talking about syntax, but about semantics. He is trying to make entrypoint runnable just after it has to be run...

Comment: Nothing wrong bout that. ENTRYPOINT is just a information stored in the container what to do when `docker run` is invoked. It is only text, an array of strings. RUN is executed during build.  MCVE for you - build and run the following dockerfile: `from alpine`
`entrypoint /file.sh`
`run echo echo Hello world > /file.sh && chmod +x /file.sh`. It will output `Hello world` but the file.sh is created after entrypoint. | How do you differentiate "syntax" from "semantics"? Syntax is set of rules, semantics is the meaning behind words. The dockerfile is valid, it's the syntax and meaning is ok

Comment: Is it due to the `USER root` line? i.e. it'll copy the file as the kibana user, so `entrypoint.sh` will end up in kibana's home. You could instead just be explicit in the paths - e.g. `COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh` and `RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh`

Comment: @kjr it didnt work Result :Step 6/6 : RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 42a3189be4de
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
ERROR: Service 'kibana' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /entrypoint.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Why do you want to give "+x" permissions as part of Dockerfile. Just give the permission to the file in your local machine and then add the file.

Comment: Also why are you waiting for elastic to be up prior to starting Kibana in your entrypoint script? You can just start Kibana (using the default entrypoint) and it will continually poll until elastic is running.